# Java - Garbage arraylist field of objects in static arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, static, garbage-collection

please look at this :

```
class MyUtility{

public static MyStock stock;

}

class MyStock{

public ArrayList<SomeThing> myListOfThings;

}


class SomeThing{

public ArrayList<WhatEver> myWhatever;
public double [] myArray;

}
```

so i can everywhere access MyUtility.stock (thread safe is not the question)

I know the GC wont clean "myListOfThings", and i dont care : this list is global and static for good reason.

But Will the GC clean "myWhatever" ? And if not, how to force/let it elligible to ?

i mean : if in the life of one "SomeThing" , "myWhatever" arraylist size goes to 123 then 0, or myArray goes from new double[123] to null;

Comment: you can't force the GC, you can only request it to run.

Comment: i know, i dont want to force i want to be ensure that "myWhatever" or "myArray" are "elligible to" GC even if "stock" is static

Comment: myArray = null; that automatically makes it eligible

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force GC to run.

> Automatic garbage collection is the process of looking at heap memory,
>   identifying which objects are in use and which are not, and deleting
>   the unused objects. An in use object, or a referenced object, means
>   that some part of your program still maintains a pointer to that
>   object. An unused object, or unreferenced object, is no longer
>   referenced by any part of your program. So the memory used by an
>   unreferenced object can be reclaimed.
>
> In a programming language like C, allocating and deallocating
>   memory is a manual process. In Java, process of deallocating memory is
>   handled automatically by the garbage collector.
>      https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

If you want GC to be able to clear memory used "myWhatever"
then you need OR to clear the list: so any objects hold by the list(but not referenced in other part) will be cleared or make the list null it will have the same effect.

```
myWhatever.clear();
```

OR

```
myWhatever = null;
```

In first case you will still have the reference to an empty list, so you will not have to recreate it, in second case you will mark also the reference to the list that is eligible for GC.

Comment: bymyWhatever.clear(); doesn't necessarily mark the bymyWhatever to be eligible for GC, only its content

Comment: Correct, but releasing memory hold by the content of a list you basically release the memory used by the list.

Comment: even if "Stock" is static (not elligible to GC) ?

Comment: static Stock has nothing to do with your object "myWhatever" . As soon as you will release the reference to the object, the GC will know that it can clear it. The same is for "myListOfThings". The only issue here can be that you use those objects(lists) in other parts of the code, and in that case you should take care about that, otherwise you may get memory leaks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your question. I think it will be good for you to read some info about java references, what they are, how to release them, how to use them, what is a static reference, when it is initialized and when is garbage collected. In that case you will answer allot of your doubts. For your case explained here , you have the answer in my response.

Comment: @Ledahu it’s dead simple. Either the list contains a reference to an object or not. If it does, the object can not get garbage collected. If you `remove` it or remove all objects via `clear`, it can.

Answer (score 0):

System.gc() lets JVM know that you want to garbage collect, it does not guarantee that it will happen though.

Your object can be garbage collected when there are no more references pointing to it.